# Cardinals, universe levels, sheaves and predicativity

Tags: dependent-type

This question stems from some of my attempts to understand [topos of coalgebras over a comonad](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topos+of+coalgebras+over+a+comonad#general) from type-theoretic point of view.
Paraphrasing the statement I am trying to understand (proposition 2.1, bullet point 1; then bullet point 3 in the link)

Let ℰ be a topos. Then if a comonad T : ℰ → ℰ is left exact, then the category of coalgebras T-CoAlg(ℰ) is itself an (elementary) topos. If T is furthermore accessible and ℰ is a sheaf topos, then also T-CoAlg(ℰ) is a sheaf topos.

Now there are 2 pieces about this I wonder about.

Can we define sheaf topoi predicatively, even though their internal language is impredicative?

How would we state accessibility within predicative type theory?
Normally accessibility tends to be defined in terms of existence of some cardinal. What can we say about cardinals type-theoretically and predicatively? Can we obtain a universe level independent notion of cardinals useful for accessibility or would we want to treat cardinals involved as more general sizes and think of them as universe levels?

Comment: I worry that in a predicative metatheory one will not be able to prove that `Set` gives an (elementary) topos. There will be no subobject classifier. One could ask this question for predicative topoi, which van den Berg lists as open at the end of "predicative topoi" but it seems plausible

Comment: This is *really* a question for mathoverflow/cstheory...